# How to create a URL in a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

i want to know how to generate a url in a servlet. I have a login servlet, and every time that add a user i want to gen. a url for each user profile.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution of kgiannakakis is very good. I just want to add some details, because reading the comment of  Agusti-N I have the suspect that may be he is missing something.

Let's say that you have the **UsersServlet** described by kgiannakakis, a jsp called **showUserProfile.jsp** and an **userBean** that has all the properties of the user's profile needed to be shown in the jsp.

When a new user registers to your application, you need to do nothing more than you already do now. Just register a new user in the db, and **forget the login servlet**.

Now suppose that I registered to your app with my username **alexmeia**.

When someone digit the url *yourApp/Users/alexmeia* the **UsersServlet is called**. This servlet gets the username alexmeia from the request url, checks in the DB if
this username exists and if exist **load all the properties of this user in the userBean**.

After that, forward to **showUserProfile.jsp**, which shows the user profile reading it from the userBean.

Obviously, if the user alexmeia is not in the Db, you can redirect to a generic userNotFound.jsp, or go to home page and show a message and so on...

This works for all the registered users in the same way. You don't need to really create a real new url for every new user.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to declare a servlet mapping like the following:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UsersSelvlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Users/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, whenever you get a request for MyApp/Users/UserId you read the request path, get the userId and check if the user exists. If not you return 'Not found'. Otherwise you return the user's page.

This is a quick and dirty implementation of a RESTful service.

Comment: if the user's page does not exist, how i will return the user's page ?

Comment: You will generate the user's page "on the fly", whenever it is requested.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to look into [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) technologies. There is a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/x-dw-x-restatompp.html) here you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need URL rewriting? Something like [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch07_03.htm), perhaps, but instead of RMI generate your own user id